# What will the average amount be by year 2025 and 2050?

Tags: percentages

The HDI for Burkina Faso is $0.388$. Annually, its average HDI increases by $2.6090\%$. If this continues what will the HDI be by $2025$ and again by year $2050$?

Comment: Instead of thinking how much is added to the HDI, what can you multiply 0.388 by to get next year's HDI?

Answer (score 1):

If this year's HDI is $x$, next year it will be
$$x + \frac{2.6090}{100}x = \left(1 + \frac{2.6090}{100}\right)x = 1.026090x$$

If you repeat the above reasoning (for example, call the result $y$ and calculate again), you will obtain that, after $n$ years, the HDI will be
$$1.026090^nx$$

Therefore, by $2025$ it will be
$$1.026090^{2025-2014}\cdot0.388 \approx 0.5150765$$

You can repeat the calculation with $2050$.